# Add object when mapping in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map from an Entity Framework object to the DTO object, I am getting the error on the automapper profile:

```
The type 'ClaimToTemplateClaim' cannot be used as typed parameter
'TValueResolver' in the generic type or method
'IMemberConfigurationExpression<TemplateEntity, Template,object>.ResolveUsing<TValueResolver>()'.
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ClaimToTemplateClaim'
to 'AutoMapper.IValueResolver<GPS.Auth2.Service.DataAccess.Objects.TemplateEntity, GPSAuth2ServiceInterface.Objects.Template, object>.'
```

**Source Object DTO**

```
public class Template
  {
    public Template()
    {
      this.Claims = new List<Claim>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
  }


public class Claim
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductNumber { get; set; }
    public string TheClaim { get; set; }
  }
```

**Entity Object (adds a join table)**

```
public class TemplateEntity
  {
    public TemplateEntity()
    {
      this.TemplateClaims = new List<TemplateClaimEntity>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TemplateClaimEntity> TemplateClaims { get; set; }
  } 

public class TemplateClaimEntity
  {
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public int ClaimId { get; set; }
    public ClaimEntity Claim { get; set; }
    public TemplateEntity Template { get; set; }
  }

public class TemplateEntity
  {
    public TemplateEntity()
    {
      this.TemplateClaims = new List<TemplateClaimEntity>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

When someone passes my a claim, I need it to essentially map to a ClaimEntity object, but also create a TemplateClaimObject.

**AutoMapper Profile**

```
public Auth2SetupMappings()
{    
  this.CreateMap<Template, TemplateEntity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TemplateClaims, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<TemplateClaimToClaim>()) <- ERROR HERE
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Claims, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ClaimToTemplateClaim>()); <- ERROR HERE
}


public class ClaimToTemplateClaim : IValueResolver<Claim, TemplateClaimEntity, TemplateClaimEntity>
{
  public TemplateClaimEntity Resolve(Claim source, TemplateClaimEntity destination, TemplateClaimEntity member, ResolutionContext context)
  {
    return new TemplateClaimEntity
    {
      Claim = new ClaimEntity
      {
        Claim = source.TheClaim,
        Id = source.Id,
        ProductNumber = source.ProductNumber
       }
    };
  }
}

public class TemplateClaimToClaim : IValueResolver<TemplateClaim, Claim, Claim>
  {
    public Claim Resolve(TemplateClaim source, Claim destination, Claim member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
      return new Claim
      {
        ProductNumber = source.Claim.ProductNumber,
        Id = source.Claim.Id,
        TheClaim = source.Claim.TheClaim
      };
    }
  }
```

Essentially we do not want to pass the join table to the DTO.

Comment: What version of Automapper?

Comment: Using AutoMapper (6.1.1)

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Your `TemplateClaimToClaim` class implements a different generic interface. It should be `IValueResolver<GPS.Auth2.Service.DataAccess.Objects.TemplateEntity, GPSAuth2ServiceInterface.Objects.Template, object>`.